# MVC Authorise logged in user updating own profile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

This is maybe a little bit of an open ended question.

Basically, I have an MVC project, people can log in and create a profile.  If they are logged in and on their profile page they display Edit buttons to enable them to be able to edit sections of their profile.

This is done via an attribute in the View Model that checks if the profile username matches the logged in username.

What I'm having a little trouble with is when posting back to update details via ajax, how can I ensure the user is updating his profile and no one else's.  I obviously want to make sure no one can hack the site and update someone else's profile.

Do I just have a check in the action that checks if the logged in user matches the profile they are on... if it doesn't then return a 401?  Is there a sexier way of doing this?  Custom Attribute etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) (or a subclass of it) to protect your controller actions from unauthorized access.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
    // edit model here
}
```

Secondly, to ensure that the user doesn't update somebody else's profile, you should design your action method to use the current user instead of putting it into the URL.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
    // Only allow the logged in user to edit their own profile
    // TODO: Update the user's database record by using the user variable as the key.
    var user = User.Identity.Name;

    // edit model here
}
```

Third, you should use the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in conjunction with the [AntiForgeryToken HTML helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to ensure your pages are posted to the server by the same browser that requested them.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
    // Only allow the logged in user to edit their own profile
    // TODO: Update the user's database record by using the user variable as the key.
    var user = User.Identity.Name;

    // edit model here
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Account")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Change Password Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Change password" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Another thing you could do is to add a second identifier to the user table that is not available outside of the application and require that any post that edits data have a one-way hash of this second identifier in it or it will be rejected. This identifier should of course be unique per user (best to do a Guid) and then use a one-way hash algorithm followed by URL encoding.

`/Account/Edit/?hash=AKXHAonyrOtruBO%2FVI%2FGr%2FM%2B4ZadjrS3YRt21ILSLntssu23l%2FN6hpUilZM8Hkgn%2Bg%3D%3D`

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Model model, string hash)
{
    // Only allow the logged in user to edit their own profile
    // TODO: Update the user's database record by using the user variable as the key.
    var user = User.Identity.Name;

    // After looking up the user, hash the hidden ID field using the same algorithm
    // and ensure that the hashes match. If not, throw a 401 error.

    // edit model here
}
```

This may help if you have a record with a sequential ID in the URL and you don't want the user to just change the ID to some other value and post it.

It helps to analyze the Account controller that is generated when you make a brand new MVC project from the VS template to see how it is put together.

Comment: Yup, exactly what I thought.  So is there no way a hacker could fake the User.Identity.Name?

Comment: lol.... I wouldn't say that now there is no way someone can hack the profile page , but it's a start...

Comment: @DotNetHaggis: `User.Identity.Name` comes from the actual authentication between the user and ASP.NET. If that's hacked, then it's the authentication itself that's been hacked.